# SUBLIME Theme Color Scheme Modifications

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext2, color-scheme

I'm using `Sublime Text 2` and the Color Scheme is `iPlastic`. How can i change the followings:

- Modified/Edited Tab Bar FONT COLOR (Current is 'red')
- Highlighting Current Line (Currently i do not have highlighting for current line)
- Change the background color of CODE AREA (White-area in the picture)

I showed as the Screenshot below. I believe/hope i need to modify the `iPlastic.tmTheme` file. But for those certain things above, i don't know what tags to add.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change current tabs font color, you have to find `"class": "tab_label"` elements in your `.sublime-theme`, and modify or add an `"fg"`. Something like this:

```
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected"]}],
    "fg": [255, 0, 0]
}
```

(If you didn't set any custom theme, the default is `Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme`).

To highlight current line, you have to set

```
"highlight_line": true
```

in your `Settings - User`.

To change the background color of *code area*, you have to add something like this:

```
<dict>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Source base background</string>
   <key>scope</key>
   <string>text,source</string>
   <key>settings</key>
   <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#FFFFFF</string>
   </dict>
</dict>
```

to your `.tmTheme` color scheme. Of course you should change `#FFFFFF` color to whatever you need.

Comment: Woah! although i still not getting where to put the lines about TAB COLOR, 1st issue, the rest are just like magic. Anyway, i'm start loving Sublime! Thanks! (BTW, can you also please guide how to, OPEN NEW FILES in same windows? Coz whenever i double click the files from o/s File Browser, they come up in *Different Instances* of Sublimesss)

Comment: You can set `"open_files_in_new_window": false` in your `Settings - User`.